# Fatal error in ../../video/video_receive_stream.ccafter calling webrtc from my application iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, apprtcdemo

Hi i have integrated AppRTC(webrtc demo app) application into my Application, it builds fine, but when i turn on video call its crashing with following error

```
SocketRocket: In debug mode.  Allowing connection to any root cert


#
# Fatal error in ../../video/video_receive_stream.cc, line 119
# last system error: 0
# Check failed: decoder.decoder
# 
#
```

please help me out, on where it may occur and what needs to be corrected

Thanks & regards

Comment: Hi @Ravi, I am also facing he same issue. Any success with your issue yet?

Comment: Hi @prasanna Yes i have solved i have been adding the video view, multiple times so it was crashing , check if you are adding your video view multiple times ?

Comment: Thanks for replying @ravi ,will check it and find out the problem!

Comment: Mine is crashing when trying to setRemoteDescription using a remote sdp. It has nothing related with the video view. any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Any resolve with setRemoteDescription?